# Cómo uno dos .txt en un solo archivo?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo que crear un nuevo archivo con el contenido de otros dos archivos, es decir, en un archivo tengo los números pares y en otro los impares, tengo que crear un archivo nuevo que contenga los números de los dos archivos de manera intercalada.

```
f=open("parells.txt","r")
f1=open("senars.txt","r")
f2=open("1a100.txt","w")

lista=[]
for i in f1:
    lista.append(i)
    for e in f:
        lista.append(e)
```

Este código me funciona a medias, no me intercala los números.

Comment: no los intercala por que estas poniendolo en un for anidado el del otro, lo que haces es recorres el 1 luego supongo se meten todos los impares y ya siguen los demas impares

Comment: Algo muy sencillo que puedes hacer es usar el lista.sort() y ya despues de esto queda ordenada

Comment: Pero cómo lo hago ?

Comment: pues despues de tu for pones eso lista.sort() y ya queda ordenada

Comment: Si, pero tengo que intercalarlos directamente. No puedo usar sort.

Comment: tienen la misma cantidad de numeros los dos .txt?

Comment: Sí, los dos tienen 50 números.

Comment: ok en python casi no lo utilizo pero si son del mismo tamaño pues es simple solo pon for i in f1: lista.append(i) (usas una variable auxiliar) aux lista.append(f[aux]) aux ++ no se si me entiendas

Comment: Funciono o que hiciste??

Answer (score 1):

Como no son muchas las líneas a leer, podemos fácilmente cargarlas en dos listas e intercalarlas de la siguiente forma:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

with open('parells.txt', 'r') as f1, open('senars.txt', 'r') as f2:
    l1 = f1.readlines()
    l2 = f2.readlines()

with open('"1a100.txt', 'w') as f3:
    f3.writelines([x for x in chain(*zip_longest(l1, l2)) if x is not None])
```

#### Explicación:

- Leemos las lineas completas de los dos archivos con: `l1 = f1.readlines()` y `l2 = f2.readlines()`
- Ya en memoria, usamos `zip_longest(l1, l2)` que nos arma tuplas por cada combinación de líneas un elemento de una lista, otro de la otra, [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) permite que, si un archivo tiene más líneas que el otro, no perdamos ninguna al intercalar.
- Y con [`chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) desarmamos las tuplas para que vuelva a representar lineas ahora si intercaladas

**Importante**: esta mecánica tiene sentido con archivos razonables en tamaño. Si se requiere hacer lo mismo intercalando millones de registros habría que buscar una solución alternativa.